# c++: fstream::seekp changes the value of a variable it doesn't control

Tags: c++, fstream

In the program, the writeSector function calls seekToSector. When seekToSector calls seekp, the sec variable from writeSector is changed. Can anyone explain why or give a solution?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


class Sector
{
public:
    int num;
    char data[1020];

    Sector()
    {
        num = -1;
        for(int i=0;i<1020;i++)
            data[i] = (char)0;
    }

    Sector(int n,string str)
    {
        num = n;
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
            data[i] = str[i];
    }

    string toData()
    {
        string str = to_string(num);
        for(int i=0;i<1020;i++)
            str += data[i];
        return str;
    }
};




class Disk
{
public:
    fstream dskfl;
    int currentPos;

    void seekToSector(int index)
    {
        currentPos = index;
        dskfl.seekp(1024*currentPos);
    }

    void writeSector(int index, Sector * sec)
    {
        seekToSector(index);
        dskfl.write(sec->toData().c_str(),1024);
    }
};


Sector * func()
{
    Sector sec(0,"something");
    return &sec;
}


void main()
{
    Disk disk;
    disk.dskfl.open("name",ios::binary | ios::out);
    disk.writeSector(0,func());
}
```

Comment: There's very little chance of people downloading a file to look at your code. Strip it down to a minimal example that exhibits the behaviour, or at least post the relevant parts.

Comment: You're almost certainly invoking undefined behavior somewhere in your code.  Use a tool like valgrind to find it.

Comment: -1 for the "stuff stuff stuff". The reason for that rule is to prevent low quality questions which consist of a code dump and "my code no workz, why", of which your question is certainly one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`func()` returns the address of an object allocated on the stack. But when the function exits, that address is no longer valid. Additionally, if the object has a destructor (or if its members have destructors) that destructor is called.

I'm not clear why you want a pointer to an object instead of the object itself. Assuming you really want a pointer, you'll have to `new` it up so that the pointer will remain valid after `func()` returns (and `delete` it when you're done).

Alternatively, you can just return the object itself:

```
Sector func()
{
    return Sector(0,"something");
}
```

Of course, you'll have to modify code that calls `func()` accordingly.

There are people who will complain about returning a large-ish object like `Sector`.  However, in this case you can rely on the compiler being smart and returning the `Sector` efficiently ("return value optimization").